# Picking random winners

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for some ideas about how to implement some kind of contest.

So our visitors have this option that after they enter some valid code they enter to some contest. We save this and pick our 'big' winner later on. That's easy and it's done.

Now they want to add this kind of extra step (after they do the previous) to participate for some kind of "direct-prizes", where i will need to do some kind 'roll' and tell them if they win one of this other extra prizes.

Currently the only info i've available is a mysql table with the list of direct prizes, and another with the codes who are on the list for our final big contest; Also i will have to giveaway 3 of these small-random-prizes each day after launch. Also this way winners will be picker very quickly first couple days since there are more available.

So i was thinking to do some kind of mysql rand() on the prizes table, and if the result isn't a prize already took => associate it to our the code they entered on the previous step/mysql table.

But i've the feeling this is going to happen right after launch/day and then during the day other users will stand no chance since it's going to have a lot of traffic, especially the first couple days where the first user will be winner NO matter what.... adn very likely our 2nd and 3rd since all prizes will be available by the time.

So i was thinking to add some kind of date component to the rand() or date since last winner.... here is where my mind starts thinking too much.

Maybe someone who already done something like this may have some better idea?

Thanks for any advice,

Comment: Pick all three at the end of each day. Or does this have to be an instant win/lose answer for the customer?

Comment: Yes, prize.... excuse my English.

Comment: yes, it has to be instant.

Comment: You may need to get legal advice, as there are laws govening these type of things in many countries. However, if the "valid code" the user enters is pre-generated, then you can preselect winning x number of winning codes and store them in a table. Of course then you might have 0 winners one day ad 5 the next. If you must have 3 winners a day, you can only do it at the end of each day

Answer (score 0):

Easy one :

At the start of each day, pick three hours, randomly, like :

- 11:45 AM
- 09:17 PM
- 11:17 PM

Store theses info in a database, mentioning if it's already picked or not.

When someone "pick" a "instant-prize", check if one of theses dates is both :

- Non picked
- Before "now"

If so, mark it picked, and give him the prize.

Of course, if your last date is "11:59PM", chances are nobody will win it. Also, if anyone knows the dates, he will surely win.